# changing a var onclick but having a default if not set

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set a variable to have a default value, and then change that value via click on a variable that is set outside of any function, including main?

A way I would do this in PHP is $(_isset.. etc so trying to figure out if there's a way to do this in jQuery?

My problem in particular is setting var n to equal 45 if its a submit button has not been clicked. To test I try to change it to 90 on click just to see if I can do this, and it did not work obviously because var n is being initialized after.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function()
  {
    var n = 90.0;
  });
});

// RotatedTriangle.js (c) 2012 matsuda
// Vertex shader program
var VSHADER_SOURCE =
  // x' = x cosβ - y sinβ
  // y' = x sinβ + y cosβ　Equation 3.3
  // z' = z
  'attribute vec4 a_Position;\n' +
  'uniform float u_CosB, u_SinB;\n' +
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_Position.x = a_Position.x * u_CosB - a_Position.y * u_SinB;\n' +
  '  gl_Position.y = a_Position.x * u_SinB + a_Position.y * u_CosB;\n' +
  '  gl_Position.z = a_Position.z;\n' +
  '  gl_Position.w = 1.0;\n' +
  '}\n';

// Fragment shader program
var FSHADER_SOURCE =
  'void main() {\n' +
  '  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n' +
  '}\n';


var n = 45.0;
// The rotation angle
var ANGLE = n;


function main() { ... (rest of code not important)
```

No?
Then what would be the best way to go about this problem?

Here's a live example as well to kind of see what I am talking about:
jdmdev.net/RotatedTriangle.html

Comment: Just want to note your link isn't working.

Comment: Add a variable to the global scope. Just declare `var myvar='whatever`; inside your script (not inside an existing function).  that being said, adding stuff to global scope is generally a frowned upon practice.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You need to set the value of `n`, instead of redeclaring one in the function scope:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function()
  {
      n = 90.0; // n should already exist
      ANGLE = n; // update again.
  });
});
```

Based on your code, it looks like you might also need update the ANGLE variable.

A submit (in most cases) will cause the page context to refresh. To maintain the value, you could use localstorage, and re-pull it down on page load.

Comment: yeah i think i'll just make a cookie set it to 45 and then change the cookie whenver someone clicks the link, thanks for the help, for some reason this was not working for me, I have no idea why either but oh well I appreciate the help!